# In the Django admin is there a way to have a list filter at the top instead of the side

Tags: django, admin

I would like to filter on some columns that only have a couple of possible values, with only a couple of values the side filter wastes a lot of screen real estate I need for data. So I was wondering if there was some way to have a filter in the top bar next to the date selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Grappelli](http://www.grappelliproject.com/). It is a very popular django app, it modifies the admin interface and the filter section (to be pop-up instead of fixed to right)

Comment: we did eventually switch to grappelli and this was one of the major motivators

Answer (score 1):

If you want that, you are essentially talking about modifying django admin template behavior. For that you would need to create a admin template in you own django app and you can change the way the template is rendered...